# Достать ссылки на картинки из SQLite

Tags: sqlite

Есть бд с таблицей _year и столбцом в ней _foto integer. В нём находятся ссылки на картинки (а именно R.drawable.img). Как можно в int[] массив занести эти ссылки?

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь, что ссылки можно поместить в массив int[], потому что ссылки обычно текстовые, а int - числовой тип данных. И еще в БД никаких массивов нет, надо указать в каком языке у вас этот массив и неплохо бы еще показать, что вы сами пытались сделать

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю, это Android и Java.

Можно выполнить запроc к SQLiteDatabase:

```
rawQuery("select _foto from _year", new String[]{})
```

Получить Cursor и обойти его:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    list.add(cursor.getInt(0));
}
```

После конвертировать список в массив:

```
int[] array = new int[list.size()];
list.toArray(array);
```